# Block messages in certain channels discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to block certain messages in certain channels but with the code I have right now, the words are blocked in every channel on the Discord. I only want to block this words in channels that are in the database. Is there a way to do this?

```
  if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/'||'discordapp.com/invite/'||'discord.me/'||'discord.com/')) 
    return blacklist.set(message.author.id, 'blacklisted');
```

Comment: What database? Also why not just query the database and check if `message.channel.id` is in your database?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you could do.

```
let forbiddenWords = ["discord.gg", "discordapp.com/invite"];
let forbiddenChannels = ["a channel id", "another one"];

for (var i = 0; i < forbiddenWords.length; i++) {
    if (message.content.includes(forbiddenWords[i])) {
        if (forbiddenChannels.includes(message.channel.id)) {
            return blacklist.set(message.author.id, 'blacklisted');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to change `forbiddenChannels.includes[message.channel.id]` to `forbiddenChannels.includes(message.channel.id)`

Comment: You should use `Array.prototype.some()` instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: Not too sure. Maybe OP wants to know which words were blocked - not only the first one found.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is check if the channel the message came from is actually the channel where you want to block the words. You can do that with the [`channel.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) parameter.

```
if (message.channel.id === "your id here") {
    // the rest of your code
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to block multiple channels you should use

```
let YourDatabaseForChannels = ["Your channel", "Your other channel"];

if (YourDatabaseForChannels.includes(message.channel.id)) {
    // the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to block several channels.